# Using "Google Tag Manager" with "Google classic Sites"

Tags: google-sites, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use [Google Tag Manager](http://www.google.co.in/tagmanager/) for a site created using [Google classic Sites](https://sites.google.com/sites), but I haven't had any luck so far. This question seems to have been up on a few forums, but I was not able to find any definitive answer to this end.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably seen this page - [Configure Google Analytics for Google Sites](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=en), but I don't believe there is a way to add custom javascript to a google sites page, at least not yet. You might be better off buying your own domain and hosting it somewhere if you want access to GTM.

Comment: Yeah. I figured as much. I was just hoping that SO might be able to provide some kind of work-around. Thanks all the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the 'embed' option in google sites to add arbitrary html/css/javascript to the site. I added the tracking code created by google tag manager and embedded it in the footer of my google site.

[Directions from Google](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-html-css-or-javascript-code-to-your-site)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my side. 
Even without embedded code, google tag manager seems to work with Google Sites when google tag manager is in preview/debug mode. But when I stop debug mode, the external trackers stop receiving events after some time.

Comment: Please bear in mind that this question is about "classic Sites" (based on the question date), the link applies to "new Sites".